# Docker container accessible to localhost when container is runned manually but not when runned by a jenkinsfile

Tags: docker, tcp, port

im running a spring boot app on a container exposed on **PORT:8084** .
the image is pushed to docker hub then i have this script on Jenkinsfile that runs the image on a container :

```
stage('Deploying the image into a container'){
        steps {
            echo "Installing the app "
            sh 'docker run $imagename:$BUILD_NUMBER -p 8084:8084 -d --name $dockerImage  '
        }
    }
```

the app is not accessible on 'localhost:8084' the container is up and when running `docker-ps` :

```
33f8cb4d98e6   28609002/time_sheet_dev_ops:38   "java -jar time_shee…"   29 minutes ago   Up 3 seconds   8084/tcp   focused_merkle
```

but when i run the image manually in my terminal , the app is accessible :

```
docker run -d -p 8084:8084 imagename
```

when running `docker ps` :

```
50715adaa50c   28609002/time_sheet_dev_ops:latest   "java -jar time_shee…"   8 seconds ago   Up 7 seconds   0.0.0.0:8084->8084/tcp, :::8084->8084/tcp   distracted_shamir
```

the only difference is in port output, i tried adding `-b 0.0.0.0` to the run command , also tried accessing the app via '127.0.0.1:8084' and many other solutions yet nothing seems to make it work whithin the CI/CD pipeline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try options after `run` and before `image`.

Here is `docker run --help` output:

```
 docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]
```

So, proper command:

```
sh 'docker run -p 8084:8084 -d --name $dockerImage $imagename:$BUILD_NUMBER'
```